# Swift Dictionary sorted keys extension

Tags: ios, swift, dictionary, swift-dictionary

I'm using a **Dictionary's** keys as the `datasource` of my `tableview`. The Dictionary's type is `[String: [Question]]`.

The problem is that the array returned from `Dictionary.keys` is not a sorted array, but I want it to be sorted. Create a function to sort the keys array could be a solution, but it's not decent enough for me, because you have to call that function every time you access the keys.

One idea came out of my mine is, to make an extension of **Dictionary**, something like this,

```
extension Dictionary where Key: StringLiteralConvertible {
    var sortedKeys: [String] {
        get {
            return keys.sort{ $0.0 > $1.0 }
        }
    }
}
```

But it tells me that "Type is expression is ambiguous without more context". Can anyone tell me if this is possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
extension Dictionary where Key: Comparable {
    var sortedKeys: [Key] {
        get {
            return keys.sort{ $0 > $1 }
        }
    }
}
```

- To use `>`, `Key` needs to be `Comparable`.
  (This ordering is what you want? You use `<` for ascending order.)
- This extension works for `Dictionary` where `Key` may not be `String`.
- In `keys.sort`, `$0` and `$1` are of type `Key`, not `(Key, Value)`.